# Java7 GregorianCalendar timeInMillis from collection are not working well

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to record a collection of objects that keep: Date, and average Day temperature.
and I need to be able to track back the date.

So I created a class that keeps these values and I made an ArrayList that keeps these objects.

In my code I test to keep 5 days. When I run the program and the ArrayList gets filled everything seems fine and the terminal displays:

dateSaved:2013-10-16 11:59:59 TimeStamp: 1381960799018
dateSaved:2013-10-17 11:59:59 TimeStamp: 1382047199018
dateSaved:2013-10-18 11:59:59 TimeStamp: 1382133599018
dateSaved:2013-10-19 11:59:59 TimeStamp: 1382219999018

These TimeStamps are all unique and seem to be fine.

however when I then enter the for loop and want to get the timestamps from each of these entries I get:

entry: 0 //removed since the first dateSaved has not been pasted*
entry: 1 timeInMillis: 1382306399018
entry: 2 timeInMillis: 1382306399018
entry: 3 timeInMillis: 1382306399018
entry: 4 timeInMillis: 1382306399018

These are all the same times and are: Sun, 20 Oct 2013 21:59:59 GMT

That is the date here. but not the time. And i'm not realy getting the values I expect to get.

What is going wrong here?

```
    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    GregorianCalendar beginDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    beginDate.roll(beginDate.DAY_OF_YEAR ,-5);


        while(beginDate.getTimeInMillis() < date.getTimeInMillis() )
    {
        GCalAndDouble dateAndTemp = new GCalAndDouble(beginDate, WeatherStation.Instance().getValue(Enums.MeasurementType.outsideTemperature, Enums.ValueType.average, beginDate) );

        list.add(dateAndTemp);

        System.out.println("dateSaved:" +  new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd KK:mm:ss").format(new Timestamp(beginDate.getTimeInMillis())) + " TimeStamp: " + beginDate.getTimeInMillis() );

        long timeTemp = beginDate.getTimeInMillis();
        beginDate.setTimeInMillis(timeTemp + 86400000); // + the ammount of milliseconds in a day.
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        GCalAndDouble tempdateandtemp = list.get(j);

        long timestamptemp = tempdateandtemp.getDate().getTimeInMillis();

        System.out.println("entry: " + j + " timeInMillis: " + timestamptemp);
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `beginDate` object.  This means that all the values will be the same.  They might have changed as you were building the list, but the final value is all you will see.

Most likely you intended to create a new Date() object for each entry to give each one a different Date.  BTW I prefer to use `long` which is not only more efficient but doesn't have this issue.